# Is there any way to get the build number in the environment or at build-time for a php instance?

Tags: dotcloud

I am trying to get the build number available in the php instance. I will use it as a type of "cache-buster" for the static assets (css, js). Is there any way to get it at run time? 
If not, is there a way to get it at build time in the postinstall script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of ways you could do this.

1. In `/home/dotcloud/` the code directory is a symlink to the build version, so for example my code directory points to `git-16ae997`. In your `postinstall` script if you get the name of that directory and store it in a temp file, env variable, or maybe inject it into one of your config scripts, you could reference it from your program.

Putting this in your `postinstall` script will add the `BUILD_VERSION` variable to your `.profile` and be available to you from `$BUILD_VERSION` in a shell, or other languages. You might need to re-source the `.profile` after you make the change to be sure it gets set.

```
$ echo "export BUILD_VERSION=`readlink /home/dotcloud/code`" >> /home/dotcloud/.profile

$ echo $BUILD_VERSION
```

With PHP you should be able to get it at runtime with the following variable.

```
$_ENV["BUILD_VERSION"]
```

1. Another approach I have used myself on other projects is to create .version file in the postinstall that just includes the timestamp of the build, and reference that file for the build_version and use it as your cache-buster. The problem with this approach is because it is created at `postinstall` if you scale above 1 instance, you will most likely end up with different timestamps for each instance, and I'm guessing this isn't what you want.

   $ date '+%s' > /home/dotcloud/.version

I would stick with #1 since it works when you scale, and it is more strait forward.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, that worked marvelously. I ended up adding it to my postinstall script where I modified my config file with the current build number.